# Generic regex to get iOS version, all iOS devices

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, regex, mobile-safari

I am trying to find a regex that gets the iOS version from all the iOS devices. I can't do one seperately for each device type (iphone, ipad, ipod), I need a generic one.

Before I do the match, I check if it is a valid iOS device. The solution I have come up with is:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent, @"(?<version>\d+(_\d+)+) like Mac OS X");
string versionNr = match.Groups["version"].ToString().Replace("_", ".");
```

I have checked quite a few devices agent strings, and so far they all match. But I am a bit worried that it wont match all, and just checking if anyone has a better regex.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259973/user-agent-parsing-with-regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers, regex is not 100% reliable for testing user agent strings, but to answer the question how about this:

```
(i[PSa-z\s]+);.*?CPU\s([OSPa-z\s]+(?:([\d_]+)|;))
```

The first match group is the type iPhone/pad/pod and the second group is the IOS version (except for IOS 1 where no version number is present)

The corpus used may be missing some of the user agents, but you can fiddle with it.

Comment: I feel my current one works as well looking at those agent strings. Still yours might be slightly better, and the list of user agents was very helpful!

Comment: @Bronzdragon Removing a link that no longer works is fine, but I wonder whether the rest of that sentence makes any sense now. What is the *"corpus"*? Also I wonder whether the word *"fiddle"* relates to the missing link, not to dictionary meaning which is *"to move things about or touch things with no particular purpose"*.